# networkx multipath python

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using networkx library to get all shortest path in a given graph trying to simulate Equal Cost Multipath (like OSPF does):

so for example, I would like to get (given the following graph):

`H.add_edge('R1','R2',weight=5)`

`H.add_edge('R1','R3',weight=5)`

`H.add_edge('R4','R2',weight=5)`

`H.add_edge('R4','R3',weight=5)`

This output:

```
[['R1', 'R2', 'R4'], ['R1', 'R3', 'R4']]
```

That is possible doing : 
  `[p for p in nx.all_shortest_paths(H,source='R1',target='R4')]`

However, if I change the weight in the edge R4-R3 to 10 , all_shortest_paths function remains showing all paths. My question is : is there any function that show all shortest path or only the shortest path depending on the weight ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you could assign multiple different attributes to use as weights, `all_shortest_paths` does not know what label you want to use.  So by default it just looks at number of edges and ignores any weights you've created.  It has an optional argument allowing you to provide the weight.  Take a look at the [documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html).  It is called by `all_shortest_paths(G, source, target, weight=None)`.  So you need to define the weight.

In your case:

```
[p for p in nx.all_shortest_paths(H,source='R1',target='R4', weight = 'weight')]
```

will provide the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joel, Taking a look to the documentation was the key to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `all_shortest_paths` functions does not consider weight. However, in this case, your intended result can be obtained by summing the weights of edges in each of the shortest paths and choosing the maximum value.

Initialize the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([('R1', 'R2', 5), ('R1', 'R3', 5), ('R4', 'R2', 5), ('R4', 'R3', 10)])

shortest_paths = np.array(list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source='R1', target='R4')))
```

Calculate the weights of each edge in a path using a list comprehension:

```
path_weights = np.array([sum([G.get_edge_data(path[edge], path[edge + 1])['weight'] for edge in range(len(path) - 1)]) for path in shortest_paths])
```

Then select the path(s) from `shortest_paths` with maximum total weight:

```
shortest_paths[path_weights == path_weights.max()]
```